# Como hacer un new date con un formato especifico

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Estoy en un servidor ingles, y necesito que mi fecha al hacer el new date, tenga el formato de dd/MM/yyyy.
He cambiado el formato al server para ponerlo en español, y la fecha en el calendario la muestra bien, pero en mi app no.

Por defecto tenia esto, que devuelve 03/07/2023:

```
var date = new Date();
```

He probado con esto, pero no funciona:

```
var date = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```

Hay alguna manera simple de hacerlo ?

Comment: new Date().toLocaleDateString("es-ES"))

Comment: @AgustinG. me sigue sin funcionar, cuando muestro el primer new date normal, me saca esto: Tue Mar 07 2023 12:51:49 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time), cuando visualizo el date con el .tolocaledate... , me sale lo mismo

Comment: Lo tienes así `var date = new Date().toLocaleDateString("es-ES"))`  ? Si es así, puede que tengas un problema con el caché.... ctrl+F5 en el navegador para refrescar